# Why does null||null return a null value but concat(null,null) returns an empty string in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to understand the differences between concat() and || in postgres when using nulls. Why does concat() return an empty string if both sides of the concat are null?

Take this query For Example:

```
SELECT concat(NULL,NULL) AS null_concat, NULL||NULL AS null_pipes, 
concat(NULL,NULL) IS NULL is_concat_null, NULL||NULL IS NULL is_pipe_null
```

will return:

[image]

I understand that concat() ignores nulls but if all the values in the concat are null, wouldn't the expected result be a null? Is this typical behavior of all functions in postgres? I couldn't find anything in the documentaion around this scenario.

Edit:

I had a thought that maybe this was the expected result of any string function but that does not appear to be the case. Both upper() and left() return nulls if a null value is passed:

```
SELECT concat(NULL), NULL||NULL, UPPER(null), left(NULL,1)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: The idea behind `CONCAT` is not to make the string null only because one of the concat parts is null. So the nulls don't make the result null; you still get a string. Which is empty. So far for an argumentation :-) I agree, though, that this is a bit unexpected and should be mentioned explicitly in the docs.

Comment: It seems that `concat` is acting like an aggregate function (e.g. how `SUM` ignores `NULL`s). Also, note that in the documentation, `concat` and `concat_ws` are the only functions that state: "NULL arguments are ignored". So I supposed the default behavior is for NULLs to trump (which reflects the SQL standard).

Answer (score 1):

**in concat() function:**

```
text concat(str "any",...)  Concatenate all arguments. NULL arguments are ignored.
```

**Note: NULL arguments are ignored.**

Imagine this:

The input arguments `concat()` are dynamical.

So when we write: `concat('a',null,null,null,null)` => we have written: `concat('a')`

(As opposed to the `||` operator that `NULL` destroyed everything)

---

**in || operator:**

> the string concatenation operator (||) still accepts non-string input,
>   so long as at **least one** input is of a string type

So `NULL||NULL` has a wrong syntax

But why not give Error?
Because in the concat operation, if we do not reject the NULL (Like the concat function), they will overwhelm everything

`SELECT  NULL ||'aaa'||'bbb'||'ccc'||'ddd'`

output:

`NULL`

[more info](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html):

> Note: Before PostgreSQL 8.3, these functions would silently accept
>   values of several non-string data types as well, due to the presence
>   of implicit coercions from those data types to text. Those coercions
>   have been removed because they frequently caused surprising behaviors.
>   However, the string concatenation operator (||) still accepts
>   non-string input, so long as at least one input is of a string type,
>   as shown in Table 9-6. For other cases, insert an explicit coercion to
>   text if you need to duplicate the previous behavior.